# Finding detail in java files

Tags: java, file, frame

I wrote some code to find student details from a file by means of a GUI frame:

- If I successful enter data and click the search button it prints the details properly.
- If I click search again it prints "not found".

I know that the readLine() function reads the next line, but I want it to start from the beginning whenever I press the search button. How can I do that?

Below is my code so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class search extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
Label lname,lresult;
TextField name;
TextArea result;
Button search,exit;
char ar;
String lines;
int n;
FileReader fr=new FileReader("student.txt");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
public search() throws Exception
{
    setTitle("student details");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    lname=new Label("name :");
    lresult=new Label();
    name= new TextField(20);
    result= new TextArea(50,50);
    search=new Button("search");
    exit= new Button("exit");
    add(lname);
    add(name);
    add(search);
    add(exit);
    add(lresult);
    add(result);    
    search.addActionListener(this);
    exit.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{
    try
    {           
        lines=br.readLine();
        if(ae.getSource()==search)
        {
            n=lines.indexOf(name.getText());
            if(n>-1)
            {
                lresult.setText(" name found");
                result.setText(lines);
            }
            else                    
            {
                lresult.setText("not found");
                result.setText("not found");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
    if(ae.getSource()==exit)
    {
        search.this.dispose();
    }
}
public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception
{
    search se= new search();
    se.setSize(400,200);
    se.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

move below code in actionPerformed(..) method, and it should work fine.

```
    FileReader fr=new FileReader("student.txt");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Comment: now the second student record cannot be searched... It says not found even if i've written the student name in the file

Comment: That's must be because the file have multiple lines. Put the try in a `while((s = br.readline()) != null)`

Answer (score 0):

As you read a stream, a cursor marking the current position advances onward with each byte read.
As you initialize the stream once, when you read past a point, you won't have the chance to visit that part again. (Unless you rewind the stream.)

So either create a new stream over the file each time, or use a random access channel that allows jumping around (same can be achieved with `Bufferedreader.mark` and `reset` though not so optimally).

---

Also note that you read only one line in your processor method. To read a file line-by-line use a while loop:

```
String currentLine = "";
while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
   //do the funky stuff
}
```

Comment: when using while loop, it display only the last record if i ever search for it. the while loop has to be broken once the file is found

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to reset the position of the reader:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("student.txt", "rw");

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {

    // Resets to the beginning of file
    raf.seek(0);

    // rest of the method

}
```

Its method `readLine()` can be used in the same way as a `BufferedReader`'s.